# I don't understand why some pointer addresses are like this

Tags: c, pointers, 64-bit, memory-address

I'm studying pointer in C language and I have some questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c = 'A';
    char* pc = &c;
    char** ppc = &pc;

    printf("%p %p\n", pc, ppc);
    printf("%p %p\n", pc + 1, ppc + 1);
    printf("%p %p\n", &c, &c + 1);
    printf("%p %p\n", &pc, &ppc);
    printf("%p %p\n", &pc + 1, &ppc + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, let's say that

```
&c = 0117FE7B
&pc = 0117FE6C
&ppc = 0117FE60
```

I thought some answers will be like this:

```
ppc + 1 = 0117FE6D
&pc + 1 = 0117FE6D
&ppc + 1 = 0117FE61
```

but the correct answer was like this:

```
ppc + 1 = 0117FE70
&pc + 1 = 0117FE70
&ppc + 1 = 0117FE64
```

and I don't understand why. Can someone explain this for me?
(My computer is using 64 bit windows OS.)

Comment: What's the type of `ppc`? of `&ppc`? Remember pointer addition takes into account the size of the underlying type

Comment: @pmg: isn't the size of pointer the same on a given platform?

Comment: @machine_1 Yes this is right.

Comment: In pointer arithmetic, the expression `ptr + n` kinda means `(unsigned char *)ptr + n*sizeof *ptr`

Comment: @pmg then I have more question... `&c = 0117FE7B` then why `&c+1 = 0117FE7C`? If so, shouldn't `&c+1` be `0117FE7F`?

Comment: `sizeof c` is `1` (`sizeof (char)`, `sizeof &c` is not `1` (`sizeof (char*)`) (probably)!

Comment: @JuneYoon:No, the sizes of pointers of different types may vary, within certain rules of the C standard. It is very common in ordinary modern C implementations that all pointers are the same size, but it is not required by the standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil can you provide a reference to the standard for those rules.

Comment: @thurizas: C 2018 6.2.5 28 requires pointers to void and to character types to have the same representation, requires pointers to structure types to have the same representation, requires pointers to union types to have the same representation, and says pointers to other types need not have the same representation.

Comment: @thurizas: N1570, 6.2.5/28: "A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
pointer to a character type.48) Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All
pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements
as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and
alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same
representation or alignment requirements."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic is done in terms *objects*, not bytes.  If `p` evaluates to the address of a 4-byte `int` object, then `p + 1` evaluates to the address of the *next 4-byte `int`*, not the next byte:

```
int x;           // assume 4-byte int
int *ip = &x;

short s;         // assume 2-byte short
short *sp = &s;

char c;
char *cp = &c;

    +---+                  +---+                   +---+
x : |   | <-- ip       s : |   | <-- sp        c : |   | <-- cp
    +---+                  +---+                   +---+
    |   |                  |   |                   |   | <-- cp + 1
    +---+                  +---+                   +---+
    |   |                  |   | <-- sp + 1        |   |
    +---+                  +---+                   +---+
    |   |                  |   |                   |   |
    +---+                  +---+                   +---+
    |   | <-- ip + 1       |   |                   |   |
    +---+                  +---+                   +---+
    |   |                  |   |                   |   |
    +---+                  +---+                   +---+
    |   |                  |   |                   |   |
    +---+                  +---+                   +---+
    |   |                  |   |                   |   |
    +---+                  +---+                   +---+
```

So depending on the size of the pointed-to type, `p + 1` will either give the address + 1, or the address + 4, or the address + 8, etc.

Remember, the array subscript operation `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)` - given a starting address `a`, offset `i` *objects* (not bytes!!) from that address and deference the result.